# Boost converter output voltage error

Tags: power-supply, power, circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator, switching-regulator

I'm using [LT3494a](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3494fb.pdf) to generate 37v from 6v input. This is my circuit.
[image]
According to the datasheet, this chip can provide up to 40v output, so it should be able to generate 37v. Also, the simulation result also indicates 37v is achievable.
[image]
[image]
However, when I measure my design with the oscilloscope on the PCB board, the Vout is not as expected. The result is :

- Pin1(SW),Pin4(CTRL),Pin5(nSHDN) : 6.20v
- Pin6(FB): 1.20v
- **Pin7(VOUT):1.02v**

I don't know why the Vout is just 1.02v which is far away from expected 37v. Can someone help me to figure out the error in my circuit or some suggestions to debug this problem?

Thank you.

**Edit:**

The problem is finally solved by replacing R71 from 5.3M to 5.2M. The reason is probably that the actual R71 value should be a bit smaller than the value calculated from the equation provided by the datasheet. I got this value by fine adjusting an adjustable resistor on R71 and measure the output voltage at the same time. When the R71 value is 5.3M, the actual voltage will be above 40v which is the maximum rating output voltage for LT3494A.

Comment: A link to the datasheet of the LT3494a chip would be helpful.

Comment: 1: Check the SW pin. See if it does anything at all. 2: Is the regulator loaded?

Comment: I’d measure the voltage at FB pin. And how good is your layout?

Comment: @Dejvid_no1 1. The SW pin seems doesn't work because there is no charge/discharge waveform on this pin. This pin only has constant voltage 6.20v. 2. The regulator output 37v is used as the V+ of two op-amp;

Comment: @user2233709 The measured FB voltage is 1.02v which is very close to the reference voltage 1.225v. All the related resistors, capacitors and inductors are placed as close as possible to this regulator. Also, I've measured to ensure there is no short-circuit around this regulator.

Comment: Try  it with no load. Also, you are sure the output capacitors are rated for the 37V?

Comment: @RossLee Then there’s something wrong with the voltage divider. Can you measure the current to pin FB? Are you sure your 5300 kΩ resistor is good and not shorted by anything? The voltage on pin FB should not be the same as on pin VOUT.

Comment: Did you try to get some lower output voltages? Try R71 (R12) at 2M to start. Does it do anything? Did you clean out your board from solder residues? 5M is a big resistor. Something like "no-clean water-soluble" fluxes leave the pin-to-pin resistance (under IC) down to 10k and below in a humid day...

Comment: @Ale..chenski Thank you for your suggestion. I just tried to replace 5M with 2M resistor and the output voltage is correct(around 16v)!!   I will keep figuring out why the 37v can't be reached.

Comment: 5.3 Mohms looks like the correct value even for the worst case internal reference of 1.245V. If the voltage goes above 40 V and some overvoltage protection kicks in, you still have some parasitic DC leakage, either to ground under the IC, or between 6V on SHTDN pin and neighboring FB pin. Thorough (ultrasonic bath?) cleanup is still in order.